# Unknown provider: $ubiModalProvider <- $ubiModal <- loginController

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I am trying to constructing master page (SPA)for the project, which uses AngularJs and WebApi2. And each page, e.g. home page/login page/next page, will be displayed by $routeProvider in data-ng-view. Everything works fine until I started to add popup to the login by clicking change password. I got this error, as title and described as below: Unknown provider: $ubiModalProvider <- $ubiModal <- loginController

```
at invokeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js:9694:9) <div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I checked a lot of solution online, and make sure that I inject ui.bootstrap to the module by var masterApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngRoute']);, and i applied the latest version of the scripts:
from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js, and in my login controller, i defined masterApp.controller("loginController", ["$scope", "$http", '$location', 'authData', '$ubiModal', function ($scope, $http, $location, authData, $uibModal) {...}); more, in the controller for the popup, i defined masterApp.controller('ChangePasswordPopupCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, Username, password) {...});
No matter which way i tried, i keep getting this error, can somebody tell me what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constantly using misspelled

```
ubiModal
```

in your code; there is not such directive in angular-ui-bootstrap.
Correct name is `uibModal`. Correct the typos and your code will work.

Comment: yes, thank you for correcting, there is another issue, that i only contain one script ui-bootstrap-tpls.js, but also need ui-bootstrap.js.